# trying to create table using list element in html

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with this table. i never created table like this. if any one know how to create this type of table like list? Just help me! pls. all suggestion appreciated.

here is small code which i going to use:

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
li{
border:1px solid black;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
   <ul style="list-style: none outside none;">
      <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 1</li>
      <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 2</li>
      <li style="float: left;display: block;width: 100px;height: 40px;">Field 3</li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

following image will for better understanding how i required output.

[image: Table like list]

Comment: Im confused.. you pretty much already have the layout, what do you want?..

Comment: its just paint design. i am not able to create this view till

Comment: Im talking about the code. you have the layout there. You just need to style it.

Comment: yes i have a code but at the second row is problematic.

Comment: yeah i have the layout but the image which i attached like same i need output

Comment: Explain what you mean and exactly what your stuck with. And like I said all you need to do is style it to look like same.

Comment: ok..at 2nd and 3rd row are the part of 1 st row and they are inside that style i am not able apply on it

Comment: Much better, so how are you using this? Displaying data from a database using PHP or?

Comment: thanks i am using Django and AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/xFJn7/)**</kbd> little complicated but close.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third"><span class="icon">P</span> Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="second">1</li>
    <li class="first">&middot;</li>

    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third"><span class="icon">I</span> Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>

    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third small">Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>

    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third"><span class="icon">P</span> Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="second">2</li>
    <li class="first">&middot;</li>

    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third"><span class="icon">I</span> Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>

    <li class="fourth">x</li>
    <li class="third"><span class="icon">I</span> Text <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></li>
    <li class="clear">&nbsp;</li>

  </ul>

</div>


div {
  width: 470px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #222;
}
ul {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.clear {
  width: 72px;
  border: none;
}
.first {
  width: 20px;
}
.second {
  width: 50px;
}
.third {
  width: 350px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.arrow {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.icon {
  background: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
.arrow:hover,
.fourth:hover {
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.fourth {
  width: 35px;
  clear: right;
}
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Awesome! bro! this is what i want...reallly superb.

Comment: Thanks bro, I was bored ;)

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr><th>row1</th><th>row2</th></tr>
        <tr><td>
           <ul>
              <li>Field 1</li>
              <li>Field 2</li>
              <li>Field 3</li>
           </ul></td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
           <ul>
              <li>Field 1</li>
              <li>Field 2</li>
              <li>Field 3</li>
           </ul></td>
            <td>X</td>
        </tr>

</body>
```

css

```
li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

EDIT: take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kt2uq/1/)

Comment: it's same as i wrote it above  and nothing different

Comment: no.. look at the html code. i put the list in a table. check the code via jsfiddle

Comment: yes i had checked but their is no second row. how i specified in the image above..

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to convert list into a table layout. If yes, please cover your list within a div and give the css as below:

```
<div class="table">
   <ul>
      <li>Field 1</li>
      <li>Field 2</li>
      <li>Field 3</li>
   </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Field 1</li>
      <li>Field 2</li>
      <li>Field 3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  border-top:1px solid #ddd;
  border-left:1px solid #ddd;
}
.table ul
{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:table-row;

}
.table ul li {
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center;
   border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
   border-right:1px solid #ddd;
  padding:2px 4px;
}
```

Demo Link http://jsbin.com/AHOVAKOJ/1

Comment: 2nd row should be inside as i shown in image. it's part of 1st row like if i collapse 1st row then  collapse all it's chilldren.

Comment: are you trying to bind dynamic data to the displayed figure? If yes, in which platform? PHP? ASP.NET etc?

Comment: yes i am trying to bind the dynamic data using Django and AngularJs.

Comment: sorry, am noob when it comes to Django and AngularJs

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested `ol` and `ul` like this ([see this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epBIk)):

**HTML**

```
<ol class="table-list">
  <li>
    <ul class="table-list__inner">
      <li>Cranberries<span class="table-list__close">&times;</span></li>
      <li>Large<span class="table-list__close">&times;</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="table-list__inner">
      <li>Infusion<span class="table-list__close">&times;</span></li>
      <li>Sugar<span class="table-list__close">&times;</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**CSS**

```css
.table-list li {
  min-height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.table-list li:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.table-list__inner {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.table-list__inner li {
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.table-list__inner li:last-child {
  border: 0;
}

.table-list__close {
  float: right;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

You should be able to use this with `ngRepeat` quite well.